# How can I allow certain entities (e.g., names, organizations) in Azures PII Entity Recognition method so that they are not recognized/masked?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, named-entity-recognition, pii

I am using [Azures PII Entity Recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/personally-identifiable-information/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python) method in Python to recognize PII entities in a list of documents.

1. I am wondering if there is a way to pass a list of entities to the method, which will then not be recognized as PII information. These will be, e.g., names/organizations which are not sensitive in the context.
2. I would like my PII entities to be replaced with the category, rather than masked with a masking character (e.g., "Andrew" will become "<PERSON>" rather than "******"). I have currently solved this problem by adding my own method and looping through the responses. I am wondering, however, if there is a better way.

Here is an example:

```
# Function to replace detected PII entities with their respective categories
def replace_with_category(document, doc_result):
    """Replace PII entities in the document with their categories."""
    redacted_text = document
    for entity in sorted(doc_result.entities, key=lambda e: e.offset, reverse=True):
        redacted_text = redacted_text[:entity.offset] + f"<{entity.category.upper()}>" + redacted_text[entity.offset + entity.length:]
    return redacted_text
    
# Function to redact PII entities in a list of documents
def pii_redact_list(documents, language):
     """This function takes the list of 5 documents replaces all the PII entities with their respective categories. The result is that rather than ****** the category e.g., <ORGANISATION> is listed in the string.
    The function first detects the language of all the documents. Next, it recognizes the PII entities. Finally it replaces the PII entities with their categories."""
    responses = azure_text_analytics_client.recognize_pii_entities(documents, categories_filter=pii_categories, language=language)
    redacted_texts = []
    for idx in range(0, len(responses)):
        doc_text = documents[idx]
        doc_result = responses[idx]
        redacted_text = self.replace_with_category(doc_text, doc_result)
        redacted_texts.append(redacted_text)
    return redacted_texts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1:**
You can simply check at the moment when you replace your items using the result:

```
for entity in sorted(doc_result.entities, key=lambda e: e.offset, reverse=True):
        redacted_text = redacted_text[:entity.offset] + f"<{entity.category.upper()}>" + redacted_text[entity.offset + entity.length:]
```

you can check if your `entity.text` matches one of the values you would like to keep

**Point 2**: this looks like a correct way

Comment: Thank you! I'll proceed with your solution for now. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it directly using the Azure TextAnalytics client. Basically, so save me from looping through all the detected entities.

Comment: As far as I know, no, there is no direct option